# Excluding HTML-Elements (recursive=False not working)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The idea is, to check the last 3 pages of a german medical-news-page. On each of these pages are 5  with links to separate articles. The program checks, if the "href" of each  is already existing in a data.csv. If not, it adds the "href" to the data.csv, follows the link and saves the content to an .html-file.

the content of each article-page is:

```html
<html>
..
..
<div class="newstext">
 <p> article-piece 1</p>
 <p> article-piece 2</p>
 <p> article-piece 3</p>
 <div class="URLkastenWrapper">
  <div class="newsKasten URLkasten newsKastenLinks">
   <p> not wanted stuff</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <p> article-piece 4</p>
 <p> article-piece 5</p>
</div>
```

I want to save the "article-pieces" to the html and exclude the "not wanted stuff".

I tried to use `recursive=False` as shown in my code.
As far as my research goes, this is the way to go, to reach my goal, right?

But for some reason, it does not work :(

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanicalsoup

# this requests the first 3 news-Pages; each of them contains 5 articles
scan_med_news = ['https://www.aerzteblatt.de/nachrichten/Medizin?page=1', 'https://www.aerzteblatt.de/nachrichten/Medizin?page=2', 'https://www.aerzteblatt.de/nachrichten/Medizin?page=3']

# This function is ment to create an html-file with the Article-pices of the web-site.
def article_html_create(title, url):
    with open(title+'.html', 'a+') as article:
        article.write('<h1>'+title+'</h1>\n\n')
        subpage = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html5lib')
        for line in subpage.select('.newstext p', recursive=False):
            #this recursive:False is not working as i wish
            article.write(line.text+'<br><br>')

# this piece of code takes the URLs of allready saved articles and puts them from an .csv in a list
contentlist = []
with open('data.csv', "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        for item in line.strip().split(','):
            contentlist.append(item)

# for every article on these pages, it checks, if the url is in the contenlist, created from the date.csv
with open('data.csv', 'a') as file:
    for page in scan_med_news:
        doc = requests.get(page)
        doc.encoding = 'utf-8'
        soup = BeautifulSoup(doc.text, 'html5lib')
        for h2 in soup.find_all('h2'):
            for a in h2.find_all('a',):
                if a['href'] in contentlist:
                    # if the url is already in the list, it prints "Already existing"
                    print('Already existing')
                else:
                    # if the url is not in the list, it adds the url to the date.csv and starts the article_html_create-function to save the content of the article
                    file.write(a['href']+',')
                   article_html_create(a.text, 'https://www.aerzteblatt.de'+a['href'])
                    print('Added to the file!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the parent `div` node of the *not-wanted* `p` node, and set the `string` property to empty string, which will make the children of parent to be removed from the soup. Then you can make the selections in a regular manner.

**Example:**

```
In [17]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

In [18]: soup
Out[18]: 
<html><body><div class="newstext">
<p> article-piece 1</p>
<p> article-piece 2</p>
<p> article-piece 3</p>
<div class="URLkastenWrapper">
<div class="newsKasten URLkasten newsKastenLinks">
<p> not wanted stuff</p>
</div>
</div>
<p> article-piece 4</p>
<p> article-piece 5</p>
</div></body></html>

In [19]: soup.select_one('.URLkastenWrapper').string = ''

In [20]: soup
Out[20]: 
<html><body><div class="newstext">
<p> article-piece 1</p>
<p> article-piece 2</p>
<p> article-piece 3</p>
<div class="URLkastenWrapper"></div>
<p> article-piece 4</p>
<p> article-piece 5</p>
</div></body></html>

In [21]: soup.select('.newstext p')
Out[21]: 
[<p> article-piece 1</p>,
 <p> article-piece 2</p>,
 <p> article-piece 3</p>,
 <p> article-piece 4</p>,
 <p> article-piece 5</p>]
```

Comment: This is actually a very cool idea to solve the problem (which of course has worked wonderfully). Thank you!

Comment: @Naraxus Glad, I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works. Simply change:

```
for line in subpage.select('.newstext p', recursive=False):
        #this recursive:False is not working as i wish
        article.write(line.text+'<br><br>')
```

to

```
 for line in subpage.select('.newstext > p '):
                   article.write(line.text+'<br><br>')
```

My output is (using your html snippet above and `print` instead of `article.write`) :

> article-piece 1
>
> article-piece 2
>
> article-piece
>   3
>
> article-piece 4
>
> article-piece 5

Comment: Oh... I really thought i tried the "simple" CSS-Relationship for selecting. *shame on me*. 
Thank you!